# NOT IN vs concatenate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Isn't both below SQL the same? I mean functionality wise should do the same thing?

I was expecting this first SQL should have got result as well.

```
SELECT * 
FROM #TEST 
WHERE COL1 NOT IN (SELECT COL1 FROM #TEST_1) 
  AND COL2 NOT IN (SELECT COL2 FROM #TEST_1) 

--1 record

SELECT * 
FROM #TEST 
WHERE COL1 + COL2 NOT IN (SELECT COL1  +COL2 FROM #TEST_1)



CREATE TABLE #TEST 
(
    COL1 VARCHAR(10), 
    COL2 VARCHAR(10), 
    COL3 VARCHAR(10)
) 

INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES ('123', '321', 'ABC')
INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES ('123', '436', 'ABC')

CREATE TABLE #TEST_1
(
    COL1 VARCHAR(10), 
    COL2 VARCHAR(10), 
    COL3 VARCHAR(10)
) 

INSERT INTO #TEST_1 VALUES ( '123','532','ABC')
INSERT INTO #TEST_1 VALUES ( '123','436','ABC')

--No result
SELECT * 
FROM #TEST 
WHERE COL1 NOT IN (SELECT COL1 FROM #TEST_1) 
  AND COL2 NOT IN (SELECT COL2 FROM #TEST_1) 

--1 record
SELECT * 
FROM #TEST 
WHERE COL1 + COL2 NOT IN (SELECT COL1 + COL2 FROM #TEST_1)
```

Comment: 1 + 4 = 5, AND 2 + 3 too.

Comment: But what result do you want?

Comment: To answer your qusetion, no, they are not the same; the fact that you get different results should tell you that.

Comment: Side note, the are *rows* not "records".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's put this into a bit more context and look at your 2 `WHERE` clauses, which I'm going to call "WHERE 1" and "WHERE 2" respectively:

```
--WHERE 1
WHERE COL1 NOT IN (SELECT COL1 FROM #TEST_1) 
  AND COL2 NOT IN (SELECT COL2 FROM #TEST_1) 

--WHERE 2
WHERE COL1 + COL2 NOT IN (SELECT COL1 + COL2 FROM #TEST_1)
```

As you might have noticed, this *do* not behave the same. In fact, from a logic point of view and the way the database engine would handle them they are *completely* different.

WHERE 2, to start with is *not* SARGable. This means that any indexes on your tables would not be able to able to be used and the data engine would have to scan the *entire* table. For WHERE 1, however, it *is* SARGable, and if you had any indexes, they could be used to perform seeks, likely helping with performance.

From the point of view of logic let's look at WHERE 2 first. This requires that the concatenated value of `COL1` and `COL2` not match the other concatenated value of `COL1` and `COL2`; which means these values must be on the same row. So `'123456'` would match only when `Col1` has the value `'123'` and `Col2` the value `'456'`.

For WHERE 1, however, here the value of `Col1` needs to be not found in the other table, and `Col2` needs to be not found as well, but they can be on **different** rows. This is where things differ. As `'123'` in `Col1` appears in  both tables (and is the only value) then the `NOT IN` isn't fulfilled and no rows are returned.

In you wanted a SARGable version of WHERE 2, I would suggest using an `EXISTS`:

```sql
--1 row
SELECT T.COL1, --Don't use *, specify your columns
       T.COL2, --Qualifying your columns is important!
       T.COL3
FROM #TEST T --Aliasing is important!
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM #TEST_1 T1
                  WHERE T1.COL1 = T.COL1
                    AND T1.COL2 = T.COL2);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7ccb046abb9729af3b9adbffcc9cc118)

Answer (score 0):

When you add strings in this way (using `+` instead of `concatenation`) it adds the two strings and gives you numeric value.
At the first query you are not adding strings so what you did is:

`Select all rows from #Test that values of Col1 and Col2 are not in Test1`
And actually, only first argument is cutting everything out, since you got 123 values in both tables in col1.

Second query sums that strings, but not by concatenation.
It actually convert varchars to numbers behind the scene.
So the second query does:

`Select all rows from #test where COL1+COL2 (its 444 at first row, and 559 in second row) are not in #Test 1`

And if you add rows at #Test1, values are:

`For the first row COL1+COL2= 655`

`For the second row COL1+COL2= 559`

So only the row with the sum of 444 is not at `#Test1`, thats why you get 1 row as result.

To sum up:

Thats why you see only 1 row at the second query, and you don't see any records at your first query. At the first query only first condition actually works and cuts everything. And at the second query SQL engine is converting varchars to numerics.

So '123' +'321' is not '123321' but '444'.